# Check if current user is logged in by the remember me filter in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, remember-me

How can I programmatically check if a user is logged in with the remember me filter in Spring Security?

E.g. how to do this in a Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping({"/sell-all-assets"})
public String sellAllAssets(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (isRememberMeAuthenticated()) {
        return "redirect:/login";
    } else {
        accountService.sellAllAssets(getCurrentUser());
        return "pages/myaccount";
    }
}

public static boolean isRememberMeAuthenticated() {
    ???
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl class contained the code that answered my question. Here it is

```
public static boolean isRememberMeAuthenticated() {
    // Check authentication exists
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return RememberMeAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass());
}
```

Comment: isRememberMeAuthenticated() always return false even I checked remember-me

Answer (score 1):

Why do it yourself. Spring Security can do that for you.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/sell-all-assets" access="hasRole("user") and isFullyAutheticated()"/>
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#overview for more information.

Comment: This does actually not solve my problem since it does redirect me to the access denied page and not the login page.

Comment: You can add a custom `AccessDeniedHandlerz that checks that condition and instead of doing access-denied redirects to the login page. Again this, in general, isn't something you want to do in all your controllers. You want to have it in a single location. Would be a simple extension to the default `AccessDeniedHandlerImpl`.

Comment: Actually I want to have it in my Controllers since I only use `@PreAuthorize`annotations for security. Then I could do the following as you suggest: `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('user') and isFullyAutheticated()")`.
But what if I want to add another condition to the login redirect, lets say for example I want to allow selling all assets with remember me authentication if the assets value is smaller than 100? `if (isRememberMeAuthenticated() && accountService.getTotalAssetsValue(getCurrentUser()) > 100) {return "redirect:/login";} else {...}`.

Comment: typo error, correct name is "isFullyAuthenticated()"

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more to Deinum answer,

**isRememberMe()**    -      Returns true if the current principal is a remember-me user 
**isAuthenticated()**   - Returns true if the user is not anonymous 
**isFullyAuthenticated()**-     Returns true if the user is not an anonymous or a remember-me user

Comment: isRememberMe() are the method I want to call but how do I call them from the controller? They seem to exist in the SecurityExpressionRoot class and which in turn calls AuthenticationTrustResolver's isRememberMe() method. Is there any Context class referencing them with static methods maybe?